# Is it possible to access individual microphones of an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-recording

The iPhone apparently has three microphones. I would like to access each of these microphones individually, and read the data into three separate files.

Would it be possible to actually gain access to these microphones individually?

Comment: It's either possible in both Swift and obj-c or neither of them. Because they are just a syntax

Comment: Are you talking about recording from different microphones _simultaneously_? If so, no, the hardware doesn't support that. Otherwise, sound-in routing is up to you: read up on AVAudioSession.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about simultaneously. And doesn't the hardware at least support it for noise-cancelling during phone calls?